# Are there any phrases, which describe 'lower eyes with shyness'

Tags: phrase-requests

for example:

She lowered her eyes at the moment of marriage with a bit smile

Answer (score 4):

She was being **demure**.

From Oxford dictionaries:

> [**Demure**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/demure):
>   (of a woman or her behavior) reserved, modest, and shy

Answer (score 0):

One common expression is *avert her eyes*. This can mean a more general action than lowering her eyes; *avert her eyes from his gaze* means to move her eyes away, rather than specifically lowering them.